# Creating a "language" function for my webpage in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

.

My webpage has some static text, i.e. text that never changes.

I want my user to be able to choose between danish and english language on this text.

My idea so far:

1. Create an array with all the text in english
2. Create an array with all the text in dansish.
3. Have the user choose either English or Danish and save that in the database.
4. Echo from array all the places it's needed in code, depending on step 4.

My question is: Is this a dumb way of doing it? does anyone know of a better or easier way..

/just

Comment: You could make it easier by storing a cookie with the language selection, or have it set in the URL `en.example.com` is fairly common, or even `example.com/en/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question: yes it is a dumb way of doing it.

Use the [qTranslate plugin](http://www.qianqin.de/qtranslate/).

Comment: I would have +1 you 100 times if I could :-) Great answer . And @Pjust - despite what you might see on theweb - qTranslate IS the best plugin out there for that task .